# Random unknown characters are appearing in HTML/ php web page

Tags: html, dreamweaver

I was doing my normal coding in dreamweaver when after adding a simple HTML table i tested the page in preview window as well as in browser that some random characters started appearing in between two tables. I switched to live code view and it showed `&gt; &gt; &gt; &gt; &gt;` as the html code behind these ">>>>>" characters.

**However I must mention that few days back I was doing some PHP and just to check if the PHP was working I `echo`ed these characters and I removed the code soon after doing that.**

I have even cleared the browser cache.

Here is a picture of the issue:

[image: Screenshot of editor and preview showing the issue]

Comment: `&gt;` is "Greater Than"...the symbol > is also the symbol for "Greater Than" and `&gt;`. What is your question regarding the characters on your page?

Comment: Random characters appearing out of nowhere; kind of like trying to find where that weird sound's coming from a V12 engine.

Comment: @racecarjonathan i know the symbol is greater than 'DUH'. but its random in a way that its appearing on its own there is no line of code to do that and i have no idea for why they are appearing so?

Comment: There is nothing random about that.  The rendered page on the right shows you exactly what they are.  How did they get there?  My guess is Dreamweaver made an assumption of some kind and added them in.  It's known to do stuff like that.

Comment: @durbnpoisn yes i know the sign is for "greater than" but i didn't add any! Should i just restart the dreamweaver or do what?

Comment: Seems like Dreamweaver hasn't changed (bug) since its introduction. Way back in the earliest version I used, it just changed my HTML like it felt it had to; I soon stopped using it and coding everything by hand. So, check that, including document preferences; options, tag replacement, etc.

Comment: @AyubBukhari I assume based of you not knowing how they got there that you are using the Design View of Dreamweaver and not coding the page yourself? When using a WYSIWYG IDE or using that feature in the Dreamweaver IDE random things can pop up, sometimes it omits closing tags, or does things like put `<p></p>` right next to each other with no content making no sense as you could just delete that and save space.

Comment: @racecarjonathan no i write the code myself(copy/paste alot though). I made a table then copied and pasted the code i had just written to make another of the same kind however these appeared in between for no reason!

Comment: @AyubBukhari It's DW bug. I wouldn't worry too much about it. Just delete the symbols and carry on. Either that or you have multiple incomplete tags that are contributing to that. But, while possible, I doubt that many tags are incomplete. I will be leaving this as the answer. Happy coding!

Comment: I would recommend trying a different code editor...try brackets or sublime. From my experience with dreamweaver it likes to insert random things...but in my experience that applied to css more than anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's DW bug. I wouldn't worry too much about it. Just delete the symbols and carry on. Either that or you have multiple incomplete tags that are contributing to it. But, while possible, I highly doubt that many tags are incomplete.

Comment: I found the problem. So like i said i was copy pasting a code and one of the line ended with two closing brackets >> and dreamweaver counted the second one as a code. lol. Thanks anyway i just finished downloading bracket though.

Comment: So it was the incomplete tag issue. Glad you got it resolved.