# Why are extra ">>>>>>" symbols being added to the comment at the bottom of my HTML document?

Tags: html, dreamweaver

Lately the strangest thing has been happening to the comment at the bottom of my HTML pages. I want the comment to look like this:

```
<!------- LET'S BEAUTY TOGETHER ------->
```

But, once and a while, without me knowing, strange symbols are added after the comment, and it auto generates this:

```
<!------- LET'S BEAUTY TOGETHER ------->>>>>>>
```

**Notice the extra carets at the end?**

That is not on purpose and it happens without me knowing! I have never experienced something like this before. Have you? It's not a coding error, is it?

**How do I stop this from happening?**

I am using Dreamweaver CS6.

Thank you,

- matie

Comment: It might an issue with Dreamweaver (i.e. a bug) - perhaps because you may have opened (but not closed) HTML tags further up your HTML (and DW will automatically try to close them)

Comment: I didn't realise people still used Dreamweaver these days.  Visual Studio Code ftw! The free solutions are way better/more robust imo.

Comment: At first I thought it was a merge conflict. Sometimes SVN would append characters like this '>>>>>>' if there is a conflict in it. It may be DW specific. Try https://code.visualstudio.com It's nice & it's easy to customize with the extensions!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random unknown characters are appearing in HTML/ php web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25454252/random-unknown-characters-are-appearing-in-html-php-web-page)